# Abstract Syntax Tree for "[a, b=c, [d,e]]"

Tags: python, parsing, abstract-syntax-tree

I am trying to generate an abstract syntax tree for the input "[a, b=c, [d,e]]" using the following code written in python.

Grammar:

```
list     : '[' elements ']'
elements : element (',' element)*
element  : NAME '=' NAME
         | NAME
         | list
```

Abstract Syntax Tree Code:

```
 def parse_element(self):


        if self.__token_at(1).type == TokenTypes.NAME and self.__token_at(2).type == TokenTypes.EQUALS and self.__token_at(3).type == TokenTypes.NAME:
           node = AST(self.__token_at(1))
           self.__match(TokenTypes.NAME)
           return node

           node = AST(self.__token_at(2))
           self.__match(TokenTypes.EQUALS)
           return node

           node = AST(self.__token_at(3))
           self.__match(TokenTypes.NAME)
           return node

        elif self.__token_at(1).type == TokenTypes.NAME:

             node = AST(self.__token_at(1))
             self.__match(TokenTypes.NAME)
             return node

        elif self.__token_at(1).type == TokenTypes.LBRACK:
             return self.parse_list()
```

Output:
Expecting RBRACK found <'=', EQUALS>
(list <'a', NAME><'b', NAME>)

Comment: You know you can't execute 3 `return` statements in a single method call, right? When execution hits a `return`, the method is *done*. It doesn't go on to the next `return` and execute that too.

Comment: I have tried using single return code also. Still I am not able to get '=' sign

Answer (score -1):

What do you need the format for? It has a few aesthetic flaws, you should only use square brackets for a one-dimensional set of elements, for multi-dimensional sets, use curly brackets because they fit in. Furthermore since whitespace is supported, there is no need for commas, they add noise and they are of no syntactical value to the parser. Also I see that values and keyvaluepairs exist within the same containing element, that is very inefficient to parse since the parser can't know if it should read a literal or an identifier without trial-and-error, besides it isn't very sensible to put them in the same internal container.

Concerning the code you posted, it is of no significant use. I advice you to read the source code of a good JSON parser before going any further.